# How to implement single transaction in Entity Framework 5 with both context SQL DB and DB2

Tags: c#, db2, entity-framework-5, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I am trying to implement both `DbContext` (`SQLDBContext` & `DB2Context`) in single transaction but every time facing an issue related to DB2.

It works fine with SQL but throws error when trying to access DB2.

The exception is :

> Error in DB2Entities getter.Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed.
>
> The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)

Please help me to implement both the DB transactions under single Transaction OR
if one of them fails then both should rollback.

Code is like:

```
var option = new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
};

using (var scopeOuter = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
{
    SQLDBContext.Table.AddSomething();
    SQLDBContext.SaveChanges();

    using (var scopeInner = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, option))
        {
                DB2Context.Table.AddSomething();
                DB2Context.SaveChanges();
                scopeInner.Complete();
        }
       scopeOuter.Complete();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried checking that MSDTC is installed, enabled and not blocked by firewalls on any of the machines involved (the two database servers and your development machine)? Also note that a transaction is not elevated to a distributed transaction until it needs to be, so performing a series of updates on just the SQL server would work fine even if MSDTC was not configured correctly.

Comment: I should say, installed and enabled on all of the machines and not blocked by firewall on any of them.

Comment: Edit your question to fully describe the *versions* of each component, e.g. which data server provider for .net you are using for Db2, which .net framework version, which VSAI version , which Db2-client bitness and version details.

Answer (score 0):

With DB2, you will have to enable XA Transactions for MSDTC. Since you are also using multiple databases, you *may* have to also enable Network DTC Access (see image below).

To change these settings open the Component Services management snap-in (Administrative Tools -> Component Services, or run `comexp.msc`). Then under Computers -> My Computer -> Distributed Transaction Coordinator, right click on "Local DTC" and hit properties. You will get the screen below.

[image: MSDTC Configuration]